# Xbap Application behavior change with or without "www"

Tags: c#, wpf, xbap, web, no-www

We are writing and running a `xbap` application. We use URL parameters to change the application's behaviour when the user logs in. To do that we use `System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri.Query` to get the URL parameters in the application.

Sometimes (and this is hard to reproduce), we get different behaviours depending on whether or not we use `www` in the URL (i.e. http://myapp.com/app/App.xbap?para1=para vs. http://www.myapp.com/app/App.xbap?para1=para). We have checked with our hosting provider and they recommend using links without 
`www`, which we've been doing ever since. Regardless, in some cases, the first link will work just fine and some cases it'll work as if there were no URL parameters (i.e. if I went to `http://myapp.com/app/App.xbap`). 
We have noticed that in these cases, adding `www` (going to `http://www.myapp.com/app/App.xbap?para1=para`) to the URL will result in the desired behaviour. We have also noticed that in these cases, `ClickOnce` will download/update some of the `xbap` application even though no updates were published.

Any help on resolving this issue would be much appreciated. What can we change to guaranty that our application will always work regardless of `www` vs. `no www`?

thx

Comment: (REF [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/adaf369b-f820-4f3e-a118-2947ec7ee187/#adaf369b-f820-4f3e-a118-2947ec7ee187](MSDN blog))
this did not help, first thing we checked.